# flex/bison - instruction execution delayed

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

Having issues with flex/bison. I execute one statement and the result appears only after I execute a second statement. Why?

Here's what I want:

```
d>5
3 = 5
5+6=
11
PR 2+3
5
d>5
3 = 5
```

Here's what I get (notice the bottom part of the result):

```
d>5
3 = 5
5+6=
11
PR 2+3

d>5
53 = 5
```

Here's the flex:

```
%{
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%%
[ ]     {}
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi( yytext ); return NUM; }
[a-z]   { yylval = yytext[0] - 'a'; return NAME; }
.       { return (int) yytext[0]; }
"PR"    { return PR; }
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

Here's the yacc/bison:

```
/* Infix notation calculator--calc */

%{
#define YYDEBUG 1
#define YYSTYPE int
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* prototypes */
void yyerror (char* s);
int yylex(void);
void storeVar (char vName, int vValue);
void printVar (int value);
int sym[30];
%}

/* BISON Declarations */

%start input  /* what rule starts */

%token NUM
%token NAME
%token PR

%left '-' '+' /* these done for precdence */
%left '*' '/'
%right '^'   /* exponentiation        */

/* Grammar follows */
%%
input:    /* empty string */
        | input line
;

/* line:     '\n' */
/*        | exp '\n'  { printf ("\t%.10g\n", $1); } */

line:     '\n'              { printf(" ");  }
        | var '>' NUM       { printf("%d %s %d", $1, "=", $3); }
        | PR exp            { printVar($2); }
        | exp '='           { printf("%d", $1); }
;

exp:      NUM               { $$ = $1;          }
        | exp '+' exp       { $$ = $1 + $3;     }
        | exp '-' exp       { $$ = $1 - $3;     }
        | exp '*' exp       { $$ = $1 * $3;     }
        | exp '/' exp       { $$ = $1 / $3;     }
        | exp '^' exp       { $$ = pow ($1, $3); }
        | '(' exp ')'       { $$ = $2;          }
;

var:      NAME              { $$ = $1;          }

%%

int main ()
{
  yyparse ();
}

void yyerror (char *s)  /* Called by yyparse on error */
{
  printf ("%s\n", s);
}

void storeVar (char vName, int vValue)
{
    sym[(int)vName-97] = vValue;
}

void printVar (int value)
{
    printf("%d", value);
    //printf("%d", array[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with that calculator definition, which in combination are a bit confusing.

First, the scanner never returns the token `\n` because no rule matches `\n`. In `flex`, the `.` regex character matches "any character *except newline*" (see the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)). So when the scanner sees a `\n`, it takes the default action, which is `ECHO`, and then immediately reads the next token, which causes the next input line to be read. Consequently, when you type <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>NL</kbd>, the first thing you see is that the <kbd>NL</kbd> is echoed, resulting in the blank line, and another line is read. The scanner passes to the parser, in turn, the tokens <kbd>PR</kbd><kbd>NUM</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>NAME</kbd><kbd>NAME</kbd>. Since <kbd>PR</kbd><kbd>NUM</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>NAME</kbd> is a valid <kbd>line</kbd> and the following <kbd>NAME</kbd> cannot be shifted, the production `line: PR exp` is now reduced, causing the action `{ printVar($2); }` to be executed.

And here is the second problem: none of your `printf` statements print a newline. So that action simply outputs the character `5`. Subsequently, the <kbd>line</kbd> `d>5` is reduced and `3 = 5` is printed. Finally, the scanner is called again, at which point it scans the `\n` and echoes it.

It's not generally a good idea to mix output from the scanner and the parser, because the order of execution is not obvious; sometimes the parser will require a lookahead token before reducing, and sometimes it won't, so you cannot easily see whether output from the scanner will come before or after the output from the reduction preceding the scanned token. I don't suppose that was your intention, anyway, but it's still worth saying. On the whole, I would totally avoid the `ECHO` action, including as a default action, unless you're writing a transducer using only flex.

Fixing the flex input is easy; you simply need to explicitly add `\n` to your catchall rule:

```
.|\n       { return yytext[0]; }
```

The cast to `int` is pointless. If your intention was to safeguard against returning a negative signed character, you should use:

```
.|\n       { return (unsigned char)yytext[0]; }
```

But if you just make that change, you'll find that your output gets somewhat scrambled, because it never outputs newlines. I'd just add `\n` to every format, but you might have different needs.

Once you make that change, you'll also find that you can no longer split expressions across lines. You could fix that by ignoring newlines in the scanner, but here you have to make a choice, because if expressions can be split across lines, then it is impossible to know where an expression ends until the next token is read, and you will be back to "delayed" execution.

Comment: Thanks rici, based on other resources and lots of testing, finally by reading your post I decided to implement a statement terminator, other than \n. I will try the \n solution, but for now ";" does it for me. You've been really helpful! I would vote up but I can't. Just to clarify, this was an example given to me in class, which I modified. As I am new with all flex/bison/c, I did not see the missing terminator and did not realize that I would need to implement it somehow.

Comment: @Gabriel: No problem. You can certainly use newline as a statement terminator as long as you're happy with statements being restricted to one line. On the other hand, your grammar doesn't require that statements be terminated; the only reason to do so is to force a reduction (which would eventually happen anyway). What you do really need to do is to handle `\n` explicitly, one way or another. By the way, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the outline of a checkmark under the answer's score; that will tell people that you're happy with the answer, and earn you (and me) a bit of rep.

Comment: Well, I believe a statement terminator makes more sense in this project. I'll have many other things to think about (like learning c :), saving strings into sets, implementing operations with sets...). For now, as ";" works, it will stay like that. Not familiar 100% with "reduction" right now, but I'll look into it. I'm not looking into building something to last, just to finish my semester project with working results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here it is: the statement has no terminator in this particular grammar.

As soon as I implemented ";" as a terminator for the statement, everything seems to be working flawlessly.

Added this in .l file:

```
    ";"        { return TERM; }
```

In .y file...
... add:

```
    %token TERM
```

... and change:

```
    | input line
```

with:

```
    | input line TERM
```

I believe rici answered my question, a bit more elaborate, I just wanted to state my solution after about 2 days of digging.

Answer (score -1):

Bison uses on character for lookahead, as in LALR(1).

It won't reduce

```
 line:     '\n'
```

until the character after '\n'.

To fix, you could either call yyparse repeatedly or restructure the grammar such that the '\n' is a lookahead token for the expression you want to have an action performed on.

```
line:   someactiontriggeredbynl '\n'
```

Comment: That's (a) not true (bison will reduce immediately if the lookahead token is not need for the decision) and (b) irrelevant (the productions whose actions contain the printf do not include `\n`.